# How to make container div fill up 100% of the screen?

Tags: html, css, height, containers, footer

I'm having a dilemma with not being able to move the copyright footer down to the bottom of the page, currently it insists of being at the middle of my page as for some reason when I try to inspect element in Google Chrome it tells me my container is only 471px in height (half my screen).... but I didn't limit my height anywhere in my code, only min-height at 100% so I'm at a loss.. Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks :)

I would post an image, but I need 10 reps... to do that ...

These are my CSS:

```
html, body{
height:100%;
}

body {
font-family: '', sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
color:#33767d;
text-align:left;
background-image:url();
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:#FFF;
position:relative;
margin:0;
}

#container {
float:none;
margin:0px;
width: 85%;
margin-top:20px;
position:relative;
margin-bottom:0;
min-height:100%;
}

#footer {
position:absolute;
width:auto;
text-align:center;
font-size:8px;
color:#54c0cc;
font-family:'', sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;
top:100%;
left:40%;
height:60px;
}
```

and my HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
```

--> logo and navigational bar and contact infos here

```
<div id="footer">
    All Images &#169; 2013 . All Rights Reserved. 

</div>  //div end footer

</div>  //div end container

</body>
```

Comment: Which part is showing _471px_?? Also what browser you are looking at?

Comment: Where do you close #container ?

Comment: @MrSoundless oops I missed a </div> sorry ...
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>

Comment: @NathanLee I used Google Chrome so when I preview my page, I right click on the page and went to "inspect element", there when I hover over my #container, it says it's only at a height of 471px...which equals to only half the size of the site even when I have height set to 100%, so I'm just wondering why 100% height doesn't stretch to the actual bottom of the page please?

Answer (score 1):

You Can use javascript to keep footer on bottom of your page, just calculate the height of window and height of footer

I have updated the code please use this.

```
<script>
var windowheight = $(window).height();
var footerheight = $(footer).height();
var maincontentheight = windowheight-footerheight
$("#container").css({'height':maincontentheight +'px'});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I'm really nublet with javascripts.  Firstly, do I place these within <script></script> tags in my HTML please?  And secondly, what exactly do I change in the code please?  I keep getting an error in Dreamweaver when I attempt to plug in numbers.  Also, what do I insert where it says "#container `enter code here`" please?  Thanks!

Comment: Currently I have added

`<body><div id="container">
       <script>
    var windowheight = $(window).height();
 var footerheight = $(footer).height();
 var maincontentheight = windowheight-footerheight 
 $("#container enter code here").css({'height':maincontentheight +'100%'});
 </script>

<div id="footer"></div>
</div></body>`

I changed it to a % instead of using px so as to streamline it to various browser sizes.  But I don't know if that's the thing that's ultimately messing me up thus far lol...

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
}
```

You need to remove this at first place , cause your footer is out of main layout and then adjust it.

Comment: Hmm, I have removed that line from my code and tested with top:1000px; after removing and it didn't actually change anything from the site, it still remains where it is wrongfully located --> halfway down on the site.

`#footer {
 
 width:auto;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:8px;
 color:#54c0cc;
 font-family:'Arimo', sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 top: 1000px;
 left:40%;
 height:60px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

No you have to put your code in the header (head) section

```
<script>java script code will be heer<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var windowheight = $(window).height();
var footerheight = $(footer).height();
var maincontentheight = windowheight-footerheight
$("#container").css({'height':maincontentheight +'px'});
</script>
```

Please use this code